# Win10 SplitView Animation

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10

I'm trying to implement a FlipView control in a Win10 UWP app, but I don't seem to be able to animate the transition between the open and closed states like in the Windows 10 calendar app. If I look at the default style of the SplitView, it seems that the panel size is altered by animating the Width property of a ColumnDefinition. This property can not be animated using the default animations provided by the framework. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the DefaultStyle, look for the **ClosedCompactLeft** visual state. Then modify the **Duration** for the animation on **PaneClipRectangleTransform**. Look for this animation (which is the one you will modify):

```
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PaneClipRectangleTransform"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX"
                                        To="{Binding TemplateSettings.NegativeOpenPaneLengthMinusCompactLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.0" />
```

Comment: This does not seem to do exactly what I expected. The left panel now animates on closing, but it does not when opening. Also, the right (large) panel does not animate at all, it just slips underneath the closing panel (this can be seen when applying a large Duration to the DoubleAnimation provided in the answer).

Comment: I've tried to play with this control too, unfortunately it is very limited when trying to animate the transitions when using inline menu. As of now I also haven't been successful with this :/

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `Storyboard` inside a `VisualState`. If the trigger is fired, the story will begin automatically.

Example structure of code:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                     <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Drawer">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-260">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1020" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Drawer">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-260"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

If you are using SplitView, you can code a class that extends SplitView and custom it's Style , which makes you get the `Pane` and the `Content` in your code and thus you can animate them on your own.